# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object Array to int

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class tryAgain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        //Creating array with Children object
        Children[] ages = new Children[5];
    
        //Creating new Children ages and adding em to counter
        ages[0] = new Children(12); 
        ages[1] = new Children(10);
        ages[2] = new Children (13);
        ages[3] = new Children(9);
        ages[4] = new Children(15);   

        sortArray(ages);

        System.out.print("Enter the age that you want to search: ");
        int val = sc.nextInt();
        int res = binarySearch(ages, val);
        System.out.println("Value found at index " + res);
    }
    public static int binarySearch (Children[] ages, int value) {

        int[] A = ages;
        int n = A.length - 1; // size of an arraylist
        int x = value; // value to be searched
        boolean isFound = false;

        int lowerBound = 1;
        int upperBound = n;
        int midPoint = 0;

        while (isFound = true) {
            if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
                System.out.println("Searched value doesn't exists.");
            }

            midPoint = lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound) / 2;

            if (lessThan(A[midPoint], x)) {
                lowerBound = midPoint + 1;
            }

            if (lessThan(x, A[midPoint])) {
                lowerBound = midPoint - 1;
            }

            if (A[midPoint] == x) {
                isFound = true;
                return midPoint;
            }   
        }
        return midPoint;
    }

    public static void sortArray (Children[] ages) {
        int n = ages.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            int key = ages[i];
            int j = i - 1;
 
            while (j >= 0 && lessThan(key, ages[i])) {
                ages[j + 1] = ages[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            ages[j + 1] = key;
            
        }
    }

    public static boolean lessThan(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return lessThan(x - 1, y - 1);
    
        
    }

    static class Children {
        int age = 0;
        
        //constructor for setting Children ages
        public Children (int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        //getting ages of Children from constructor
        public int getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }

        //setting new age to children
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }   
    
}
```

It giving me an error like:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from tryAgain.Children to int
The method lessThan(int, int) in the type tryAgain is not applicable for the arguments (int, tryAgain.Children)
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to tryAgain.Children

```
            at tryAgain.sortArray(tryAgain.java:63)
            at tryAgain.main(tryAgain.java:19)
```

The aim is to add some values to the object array and then sort them with sorting method, and after that find the needed value with binary search.

Comment: `ages[i]` is a `Children`, and you are trying to pass it as an argument that requires an int.

Comment: By the way, `while (isFound = true)` is an infinite loop. It looks like you mean `while (!isFound)`, but the variable seems to be redundant anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this method, what are you passing to it?

```
lessThan(key, ages[i])
```

`key` is an `int`, and `ages[i]` is a `Children` (which is unnecessarily misleading, we'll get to that below).  But what does the method expect?:

```
public static boolean lessThan(int x, int y)
```

An `int` and an `int`.  So just as the error states, a `Children` can not be converted to an `int`.  Presumably you meant to *get the age* from the `Children` object:

```
lessThan(key, ages[i].getAge())
```

---

As an aside... **Names are important**.  You've essentially confused yourself by giving your classes/variables/etc. misleading names.

What is a `Children`?  Is it a single instance of a "child"?  Then why it is plural?

What is `ages`?  Is it a collection of child objects?  Then why does it imply that it's just a collection of numeric values?  (Which is exactly the bug you're trying to fix right now.)

Rename your `Children` class to `Child`, because it represents a child.

Rename your `ages` variable to `children`, because it represents a collection of children.

Name things by what they semantically represent and your code will be *much* easier for you to read and understand.

Comment: Yeap, that worked for me. Thank you very much. Also, thanks for the naming advice I'll try it.